# Quanto utilizar @Html.ActionLink ou Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estou com dificuldades para entender, quando deve ser utilizado um `@Html.ActionLink` ou `javascript:document.getElementById('Comercial').submit()`

Por exemplo:

```
<a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
<ul class="nav child_menu">

         <li><a>@Html.ActionLink("Painel Inicial", "Index_Comercial", "Home")</a></li>

</ul>
```

Ou:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Index_Comercial", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Comercial" }))
{

}
<a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
<ul class="nav child_menu">

         <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('Comercial').submit()">Painel Inicial</a></li>

</ul>
```

- Quando usar um, ou outro?
- Quais as principais diferenças?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, este uso está incorreto:

```
<ul class="nav child_menu">

         <li><a>@Html.ActionLink("Painel Inicial", "Index_Comercial", "Home")</a></li>

</ul>
```

`@Html.ActionLink` já gera um `<a>`. Você não precisa colocar `<a>` e `</a>` ao redor dele. `@Html.ActionLink()` gera um link tradicional, cujo método de requisição é `GET`, pelo padrão do protocolo.

Já isto:

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('Comercial').submit()">Painel Inicial</a>
```

faz com que o link mude de comportamento e passe a atuar com o método `POST`, que exige um formulário para funcionar (no caso, `'Comercial'`). Neste caso, o comportamento do link vai ser igual ao de um `<input type='submit' />`.